# Fully GUI-orientated Linux Distro

Tags: gui, distro-recommendation

I have one simple question: Is there a Linux Distro available that is as user friendly as Windows or Mac, and completely GUI orientated (Zero or minimal terminal action needed)?

I have tried Fedora, Kubuntu and Ubuntu Studio, but they are all similar in the sense that you have to know what's going on in the Linux matrix in order to do the simplest things.

God knows I must have typed a thousand lines with the word `sudo` in it already from discussion forums, not having a clue what the hell I'm actually doing! ...If I wanted to type commands at a command prompt, I would have dug out my old MS-DOS 6.22 disks!

My desire to get away from Microsoft's monopoly has lead me to the Linux platform. I love that it's free and there are no license keys or online activations required, but is there a distro for teaspoon-fed Linux babies like myself, or do I need to return to the dreaded Windows?

I hope someone has a good respectful answer for me...

Comment: I believe you *can* run Ubuntu very well without a single line of cli, just like you *can* run commands on windows. An example of something?

Comment: We only support Ubuntu. For generic linux you should ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ But what you ask is also largely dependent on opinion.  And a personal comment regarding  "and completely GUI orientated (Zero or minimal terminal action needed)?" NEVER going to happen with a Linux operating system.  The command line is by far the greatest feature Linux has. I would advice to get used to it ;)

Answer (score 4):

In fact you can do almost anything in Ubuntu from the GUI, the reason why you see so many referrals to terminal commands for fixing issues, installation etc. is the simple fact that it is easier to transport a concrete solution, instead of putting up screen-shot after screen-shot or even describing which icons to click, what to enter and so on.

So for the casual usage cases you can do everything you want via the GUI already. But take my advise learn to use and love the terminal, its is all in all a quicker solution on Linux, as it is in Windows too, if user would learn to use Windows command line or power-shell, ah and I nearly forgot the new kid on the block Bash for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest: what does average user need nowadays ? A web browser. Maybe video/audio player and word processor. Might be understatement , but for most common tasks that a user needs to perform on day to day basis, that's all there is necessary. If that's the case, where all your work will be centered around a web browser, then you want Chrome OS. They're cheap and just work.

But we're talking about Ubuntu here, right ? Well, guess what - all those common tasks can be done by Ubuntu's GUI as well. My personal suggestion would be take a simple version, Lubuntu or Xubuntu, maybe Mate, and just learn to use that. They're quite light and won't hog your memory or CPU, and they mostly work fine without issues.

You said:

> God knows I must have typed a thousand lines with the word "sudo" in it already from discussion forums, not having a clue what the hell I'm actually doing!

Well, first of all typing anything from forum with`sudo` without actually knowing what it does is a sin in and of itself, just like when somebody shoves you an `exe` file on Windows and says "Here, install this" and you've no clue what it does and why do do you need to click here or there.  Bad, very bad practice. That also says something about you as a computer user. After all, computer is a machine. Would you agree that when you own a car, you have to change oil and know how to check tire pressure ? Same here. Maybe, just maybe, this is the big problem of our modern age - not owning a computer, but actually knowing how to take care of it and know how to troubleshoot.

Try to identify the core of the problem. Was it an issue with WiFi ? Well, perhaps the WiFi chip that you're using isn't most Linux-friendly. Was it graphics issue ? Perhaps you need a different driver. These same issues occur on Windows and you still deal with drivers, bugs, glitches even there. The point is, you need to learn how to overcome those issues.

Let me put it this way: I understand that command-line can be scary and confusing if you don't use it every single day. But so can be Window's utilities if you've never used them.

And let's face the facts - every system is different and has its own way of managing things, troubleshooting things, and administering things. It just so happens that on Linux, which comes from Unix lineage, command-line is more efficient and preferred by power users. In fact, there has been critique towards Windows for years to provide a better command-line, since that's what power users prefer.

Please understand, I don't mean no disrespect to you as someone who prefers GUI. It is one of the most awesome things developed in the computing world. And even in the realm of Linux you can use GUI, there's just more choices of it.  But when it comes to actually administering and fixing and being the proud owner of your computer - that's where command-line comes in and it just so happens to be the preferred method of troubleshooting.

So in conclusion , the answer to your question "Is there a Linux distro with minimal terminal interaction?"  would be simple : there's plenty of them, and it really depends on you how much terminal interaction you as computer owner are willing to invest. Since this site is Ubuntu-specific and we give recommendations only for official Ubuntu releases, I can only suggest Ubuntu Mate or Lubuntu for being light and quite simple.